# how to use count and select all when using union and show count into a label

Tags: c#, sql, select, count, union-all

I would like to ask for help about this. I am using union all with where condition, my query will show in a datagridview. My question is, is there a way that it will count the rows it will generate and show the count in a label or textbox below the datagridview? This is my code:

```
string query = @"Select * FROM
                    (
                        SELECT date AS [Date],b.fname+' '+b.mname+' '+b.lname AS Person,
                        b.pk+ ', '+b.by+', '+b.my AS Address, b.sex,
                        'PoNa' AS [Transaction] FROM dbo.POST AS a INNER JOIN
                        [dbo].PERCORD AS b ON b.idp = a.idp

                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT date AS [Date],b.fname+' '+b.mname+' '+b.lname AS Person,
                        b.pk+ ', '+b.by+', '+b.my AS Address, b.sex,
                        'PreNa' AS [Transaction] FROM dbo.PRENA AS a INNER JOIN
                        [dbo].PERCORD AS b ON b.idp = a.idp

                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT date AS [Date],b.fname+' '+b.mname+' '+b.lname AS Person,
                        b.pk+ ', '+b.by+', '+b.mty AS Address, b.sex AS Sex,
                        'Check' AS [Transaction] FROM dbo.CHECK AS a INNER JOIN
                        [dbo].PERCORD AS b ON b.idp = a.idp
                    )
                        as T where date between '" + fromdt.Value.ToString() + "' and '" + todt.Value.ToString() + "' and [Transaction] = '" + ttypecb.Text + "'";

                using (SqlConnection xcon = new SqlConnection(@"Server=QWERTY\SQLEXPRESS;Database=QWERTY;Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand xcom = new SqlCommand(query, xcon))
                    {
                        SqlDataAdapter xdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(xcom);
                        try
                        {
                            xcon.Open();
                            DataTable xlist = new DataTable();
                            xdapter.Fill(xlist);
                            trans.DataSource = xlist;

                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            throw;
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            xcon.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, is there a way that it will count the rows it will generate and show the count in a label or textbox below the datagridview? This is my code

The `DataTable` has all the rows in it once you call the `Fill` method. So you can use the `slist.Rows.Count` to get that information.

I don't believe there is any place a `DataGridView` automatically shows the total number of rows. You can display it using any `Control` of your choice. You can use Row numbers in DataGridView if that helps